# Why does "MessageboxA" function not receive input from "section .data"?

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86-64, nasm

Following code was supposed to display a simple "Hello world!" message box. But for some reason gets no message box displayed. Code compiles, builds and executes without error. Debugger shows four parameter passing registers RCX, RDX, R8, R9 registers with supposedly correct values just before function call and function itself returns 0 in RAX.

```
    %include "io64.inc"
    ; hellow.asm
    ;%include "win32n.inc"
    extern ExitProcess
    extern MessageBoxA
    section .data
    msg db 'Welcome to Windows World!',0
    cap db "Windows 10 says:",0
    UINT dd "0x00000040",0
    section .text
    global main
    main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    ;int MessageBoxA(
    ; HWND hWnd, owner window
    ; LPCSTR lpText, text to display
    ; LPCSTR lpCaption, window caption
    ; UINT uType window behaviour
    ; )
    mov rcx,0 ; no window owner
    lea rdx,[msg] ; lpText
    lea r8,[cap] ; lpCaption
    lea r9d,[UINT] ; window with OK button
    sub rsp,32 ; shadowspace
    call MessageBoxA ; returns IDOK=1 if OK button selected
    add rsp,32
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Your UINT looks very wrong. You define it as a DD made up of a string and then get the address of it. You want to create a constant out of it. Maybe try `UINT equ 0x00000040` and then do `mov r9d,UINT` instead of  `lea r9d,[UINT]`

Comment: Thanks, "UINT equ 0x00000040" solves the problem, no need to change lea to mov.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) I got reason for message box not displaying. At section .data "UINT dd 0x00000040" is given as a "character encoding". Such a stupid mistake! To correct that I have to convert that to absolute value. "equ" just does that. So "UINT equ 0x00000040" is the correct input expected by the function in question.

corrected code is:

```
    %include "io64.inc"
    ; hellow.asm
    ;%include "win32n.inc"
    extern ExitProcess
    extern MessageBoxA
    section .data
    msg db 'Welcome to Windows World!',0
    cap db "Windows 10 says:",0
    UINT equ 0x00000040
    section .text
    global main
    main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    ;int MessageBoxA(
    ; HWND hWnd, owner window
    ; LPCSTR lpText, text to display
    ; LPCSTR lpCaption, window caption
    ; UINT uType window behaviour
    ; )
    mov rcx,0 ; no window owner
    lea rdx,[msg] ; lpText
    lea r8,[cap] ; lpCaption
    lea r9d,[UINT] ; window with OK button
    sub rsp,32 ; shadowspace
    call MessageBoxA ; returns IDOK=1 if OK button selected
    add rsp,32
    leave
    ret
```

As per [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) suggestion, more appropriate coding:

```
    %include "io64.inc"
    ; hellow.asm
    ;%include "win32n.inc"
    extern ExitProcess
    extern MessageBoxA
    section .data
    msg db 'Welcome to Windows World!',0
    cap db "Windows 10 says:",0
    MsgBoxOK equ 0x00000040
    section .text
    global main
    main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    ;int MessageBoxA(
    ; HWND hWnd, owner window
    ; LPCSTR lpText, text to display
    ; LPCSTR lpCaption, window caption
    ; UINT uType window behaviour
    ; )
    mov rcx,0 ; no window owner
    lea rdx,[msg] ; lpText
    lea r8,[cap] ; lpCaption
    mov r9d,MsgBoxOK ; window with OK button and i icon
    sub rsp,32 ; shadowspace
    call MessageBoxA ; returns IDOK=1 if OK button selected
    add rsp,32
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: `lea r9d, [0x00000040]` is a really silly way to put a small integer in a register.  It's less efficient than `mov`, and confusing for humans; they'll wonder why it's an address, and have to go and see it's not an address at all, then wonder why you did it that way, perhaps for some obscure performance or code-alignment / code-size reason.  You don't *need* to change to `mov`, but you *should*.  Also, give it a meaningful name, like `msgbox_with_OK` or something.  Most programs have more than one unsigned int value, so it's not a good name.

Comment: *UINT can be omitted completely from data section possibly saving some tiny bit of memory.* You were already doing that in your first version.  The memory saving is the shorter instruction, `mov r32, imm32` instead of `lea r32, [disp32]`.  EQU just defines an asemble-time constant; it doesn't emit any data into the output as the position where you write it.  It's a bit like C `#define` or NASM `%define`, but only for integers.  That's why `lea r9d, [UINT]` gave you `0x40` in a register, not an address of some static storage.  And same why `mov r9d, UINT` wouldn't give you an address.

Comment: TL:DR: `equ` is different from `dd`.